# Why might Windows be unable to recognize two different VCP devices?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, com-port

I plug in an FTDI virtual comport device and it comes up COM5 in my device manager. I unplug it, then plug in a different USB device and the new device comes up COM6. Now if I try to plug in both, then whichever goes in second does not work. Windows says "The USB device has malfunctioned and Windows does not recognize it." For some reason I can only ever have one of the devices in at any time.

What could be happening when I plug in that second device that makes the other COM disappear?

Note: Both devices can be plugged in on a newer laptop and they work fine together. This is only happening on three older laptops. All device drivers are exactly the same on all laptops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a wild guess. If you plug both serial devices in the same hub, potentially the sum of the power taken from the hub could be excessive, overloading the hub.

Try to plug a device on each side of the laptop, so that they are on different hubs. Generally pairs of USB sockets are connected to the same hub.

And try both sides of the laptop anyway. I've noticed that one side can handle more than the other.

Comment: I tried both sides and different USBs on each side and it acts the same. Maybe it just needs to be a newer laptop with more powerful hubs? I'm going to find another new laptop somewhere and test.

Comment: If you feel up to it, you could try to look at the bus traffic with Wireshark or another USB sniffer. You should be able to see why the first device disconnects when you plug the second one in. (I'm note entirely sure Wireshark can do USB on Windows though)